# Latency Issue : Page Load performance from Aps.net site to MVC 5 site Home page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable, razorengine

I have a Asp.net web site hosed in IIS . And i have a link on that site. So, if i click that link i will navigate to the MVC site Home page which has been hosted in in the same IIS.

Issue:
The issue is it is very slow. It took's more than 10 sec to open the home page of 
MVC 5 web site. Its a cshtml with razor and has Jquery Datatable to load the data. 
Please let me know what would be best way to reduce that latency

Comment: Have you tried on another server? Perhaps it's just your hardware or environment setup. Or perhaps you have a slow-running query. Or perhaps you are trying to return a very large amount of data. Or perhaps you wrote your code really inefficiently, or didn't index your database tables properly. We can't fix what we can't see, so we can only guess.

Comment: Thanks Adyson as you said its a large amount of data its around 1.3 MB return from DB and we have it returned from a complex sql query. So what would be best to option to load such a amount of data faster. Because i can't increase the  hardware the  IIS is already running with 32 GB RAM

Comment: That's not a ridiculous amount of data, although it's a moderately large amount for a single web page. I can't advise you how to load it faster because I can't see your code, and you haven't identified where the bottleneck is. You need to investigate and identify where in the process the slowdown happens. Is it the SQL query (or related things such as indexes), or the C# code, or the Razor code, or the DataTables rendering process? You need to test each part of the process starting from the query and work out how much time each one takes, to know where in the stack the worst performance is.

Comment: You also need to do what I suggested (if you can) and switch out components e.g. run on another webserver, then another DB server, another browser / O/S / device (for the end-user), to see if it's a config issue in any of those environments. Also check if there are any network bandwidth issues in between all the different machines involved (client -> IIS Server -> SQL Server). There's no single right answer to this, but before we can even begin to consider a solution you need to understand your application's architecture, and then break it down in order to isolate the problem area.

Comment: Adyson i tried in multiple servers or in client network as well.But the latency is still the same. its a repository pattern Architecture with Entity Framework..

Comment: Actually I was thinking more of the techinical architecture than the software architecture. Anyway if using different devices / networks makes no difference, you still need to identify whether the problem is in the SQL part of the system or in the C#, or if there's a network problem in between the IIS Server and the SQL Server. You can use SQL Profiler for instance to find out how long the SQL query takes, and exactly what query (or queries) gets executed. Entity Framework doesn't always create very efficient SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI we resolved the above said issue using the below steps.
 - Instead hosting the MVC 5 site seperately with alternate port we hosted the MVC 5 site with in the Parent site. So that being said both will have the same port number.

Note: This increased the initial page load time. However made us to comment out somelines in the web.config of parent site. So after deploying the entire parent and Child need to be tested and validated.